# How to read image from pixel data?

Tags: image, matlab

[image: no use]

I am trying to read image of cifar10 dataset in MATLAB. The data is given in 10000x3072 format in which one row contains corresponding RGB value. I used:

```
img= reshape(data(1, 1:1024), [32,32]);
image(img)
```

to convert the image into meaningful because it is showing garbage image. How can I read the image from this .mat file? from this dataset https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-matlab.tar.gz

Comment: Can you explain the data format a bit more? From your code I assume your images are 32x32, and I would expect that each images has 3 channels, but I don't understand what you mean by "one row contains corresponding rgb value". The data size of 10000x3200 doesn't seem to be even multiples of any of those numbers.

Comment: yes there are 10000 images and each row is a image, I am having problem in reading them

Comment: `3200 != 32x32x3` Did you mean 10000x3072, or am I missing some information? Are the RGB components interleaved, or do you have all of the red channel followed by all of the blue channel, followed by all of the green channel?

Comment: Yes 10000x 3072 first 1024 R ,second 1024 g and last b

Comment: Then the code you have so far should show the red image (possibly transposed). Can you provide an example of your output?

Comment: no its not showing any traces of image

Comment: According to the description of the dataset (which you really should have quoted in your question) "data -- a 10000x3072 numpy array of uint8s. Each row of the array stores a 32x32 colour image. The first 1024 entries contain the red channel values, the next 1024 the green, and the final 1024 the blue. The image is stored in row-major order, so that the first 32 entries of the array are the red channel values of the first row of the image." So the image you show should be the transpose of the red channel. Add the other 2 channels and it should look better.

Comment: so how to read so that I can view a meaningful image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) page, the format of `data` is:

> - **data** -- a 10000x3072 numpy array of uint8s. Each row of the array stores a 32x32 colour image. The first 1024 entries contain the red channel values, the next 1024 the green, and the final 1024 the blue. The image is stored in row-major order, so that the first 32 entries of the array are the red channel values of the first row of the image.

Using your code:

```
img= reshape(data(1, 1:1024), [32,32]);
```

you should get the red channel of the first image in column-major order (i.e. transposed). To get a full RGB image with the correct orientation, you'll want to use:

```
img = reshape(data(1, 1:3072), [32,32,3]);   % get 3-channel RGB image
img = permute(img, [2 1 3]);   % exchange rows and columns
```